# AdMob custom event interstitial don't show

Tags: java, android, admob

I have a task to make a custom event for an AdMob Interstitial ad and to load something other into it. Everything is implemented by documentation, I set up all in AdMob dashboard, in my project to. 
In the class where I implemented CustomEventInterstitial method requestInterstitialAd is calling and that's ok, but method showInterstitial cannot be called and my custom ad cannot be shown. Instead of that AdMob shows some default interstitial.
Does anybody have idea what can be the problem here?

Comment: You must have to test with Test Ads key which are listed in this link [https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads] it will show default ads. and if you want to test real ads then you need to publish your app as a beta version or live.

Comment: I am testing real ads actually. I am testing this on emulator which is the test device and everything works except when I want to show custom event (for some interstitial ad I want to show something else). The method showInterstitial isn't called in the class which nesting CustomEventInterstitial. I am looking for the reason why that method isn't called but requestInterstitialAd is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened. In my custom listener I missed up to call CustomEventInterstitialListener when ad is loaded and later my custom ad wasn't show.
Thanks for the help and take my advice to cover all listeners when you implement your own custom event.
Cheers!